# Is it possible that making indexed color 8bit png with transparent by c#?

Tags: c#, png, transparent, 8-bit

I'm looking for the way that making indexed color 8bit png with transparent by c#.
I have to convert png except 8bit png to 8bit png.
I can make a indexed color 8bit png, but I can't set transparent into the png.
How do I make it? To begin with, is it possible?
Would you tell me if you know some good ways except using c#?
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some worthwhile ideas in this link that you can use:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jacquesphilip/MakingThumbnailsOfTransparentImages11162005004933AM/MakingThumbnailsOfTransparentImages.aspx